# test automation using samsung internet browser using appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium, samsung-browser

Used Below configuration to launch Samsung Internet browser....

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();           
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.sec.android.app.sbrowser");    
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.SBrowserMainActivity");  
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "my phone");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1.0");
URL mobile_url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AndroidDriver(mobile_url, capabilities);
driver.get(url);
```

1. Samsung default browser is lauching successfully, but shows Skip / Next button - these button navigates to browser page 
   [image]
2. elements not able interact (like click, sendkeys)
   [image]
   Please help me to solve these problems.

Answer (score -1):

Launch the browser by adding below capability `capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");`

Remove `appPackage` and `appActivity`

Inspect the screen using chrome remote debugger as shown in below screenshot
[image]

Appium docs showing when `browserName` is `'Browser'` it will launch default browser or native browser for Android

[image]

Comment: i want to automate samsung internet browser, not for chrome.

Comment: MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser" will launch default browser of the mobile which would be company browser... More over launching a browser as an app is not correct way of testing a webapp.

Comment: I have used below code ...
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTO_WEBVIEW,"true");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung");capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
AppiumDriver<MobileElement>  driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
error: 
Original error: Could not find package com.android.browser on the device

Comment: @Manjunatha.N have found the answer to your question?